# Yum repos are broken after installing Jenkins

Tags: redhat, yum

I installed apache and jenkins, now when I run yum commands I get repo errors. I'm new to redhead so I'm struggling to see where I'm going wrong.

Heres an example of trying to install git:

```
# yum install git
Loaded plugins: security
file:///mnt/cdrom/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/cdrom/Server/repodata/repomd.xml'
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Server. Please verify its path and try again
```

My yum.conf looks like this

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
pkgpolicy=newest
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
metadata_expire=1800

[base]
name=CentOS-5 Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0

[Server]
name=Enterprise Linux 5 Update 6
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/Server/

[VT]
name=Enterprise Linux 5 Update 6
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/VT/

;[Cluster]
;name=Enterprise Linux 5 Update 6
;baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/Cluster/

;[ClusterStorage]
;name=Enterprise Linux 5 Update 6
;baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/ClusterStorage/

;[updates]
;name=Enterprise Linux 5 Update 6
;baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/updates/OEL5-u6-x86_64/

;[companion]
;name=Enterprise Linux 5 Update 6 - Companion
;baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/companion/OEL5-u6/
```

My extra repo file: vim public-yum-el5.repo

```
[el5_latest]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL5/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[el5_ga_base]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever GA installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/EnterpriseLinux/EL5/0/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[el5_u1_base]
name=Enterprise Linux $releasever Update 1 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/EnterpriseLinux/EL5/1/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[el5_u2_base]
name=Enterprise Linux $releasever Update 2 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/EnterpriseLinux/EL5/2/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[el5_u3_base]
name=Enterprise Linux $releasever Update 3 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/EnterpriseLinux/EL5/3/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[el5_u4_base]
name=Enterprise Linux $releasever Update 4 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/EnterpriseLinux/EL5/4/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[el5_u5_base]
name=Enterprise Linux $releasever Update 5 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/EnterpriseLinux/EL5/5/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[ol5_u5_base]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Update 5 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL5/5/base/x86_64/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

[ol5_u6_base]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Update 6 installation media copy ($basearch)
baseurl=http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL5/6/base/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have nothing in `/mnt/cdrom/` directory. Thats why Yum gives you the following error:

`No such file or directory`

Comment: Now imagine I've inherited this server to work with, how would I mount the required files there or how would I make it skip the check to that area?

Comment: You can comment the `[Server]` and `[VT]` section or Mount the ISO Image or cdrom using this command: `mount -o loop cd-image.iso /mnt/cdrom`

Comment: You can even add `enabled=0` under each section to disable the specified repository.

Comment: Thanks, setting enabled=0 has fixed the issue and i've added the correct repo mirror. Thanks!